# Simple short circuit protection?

Tags: diodes, dc, protection, short-circuit, adapter

Basically, I have dc adapters one of 12v 2a and one of 5v 1a, which do not have short circuit protection, having said that I want to make a simple circuit to protect them, I will add the circuit to the dc output cable of the charger so as not to disassemble it, I have seen various types of short circuit protection, for example:

With Buzzer, Those who trigger sound when short-circuited and throw away said energy so that it does not return. something like 19v 4 amp adapters.

Resumable silent, which cuts the power when there is a short circuit and resumes the passage of power until a few seconds pass, disconnected from the electricity of the house.

With led indicator, those that make the led turn off when there is a short circuit and stop the power while there is a short circuit, and resume until the short circuit stops. turning on the led again.

Using fuses, which blow when shorted and can be replaced.

I'm basically interested in any of those, except the last one, the one with replaceable fuses.

Or if there is another, for example using a diode that absorbs all the energy when the switch is short-circuited.

**Here the dc adapter 12v 2a, using a switch to cause the short circuit:**

[image]

**Here the dc adapter 5v 2a, using a switch to cause the short circuit:**

[image]

**How much more simple and effective is, is better for me...**

**Led diodes ot buzzers are optionals**

**For the people who comment about the nippon adapters, I leave these images, in case they help in something!**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for a [resettable fuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resettable_fuse).

Comment: any very common that you can recommend?

Comment: Could it be simpler to buy adapters with short circuit protection? Actually, why are you sure your existing adapters don't have protection?

Comment: The resellers of my product told me that it does not have output protection Here the models: nippon dv-cc-212, 12v 2a and nippon dv-2005 5v 2a

Comment: I would contact Nippon to verify. A consumer adapter wouldn't last very long if it couldn't survive a short-circuit on its output. Especially when it's pictured with one of those CCTV barrel to screw terminal adaptors: https://www.nipponamerica.com/product-page/dv-2005

Comment: There are devices called circuit breakers that will do what you want. If you want an indicator you could put a LED in series with a resistor across the breaker contacts, that will light if the power is on and the breaker is open.

Comment: Those look like pretty casual switch mode power supplies. These usually can handle short circuits just fine, so it would be uncommon if these didn't. What do you expect to happen if you short circuit these power supplies?

Comment: Have you thought about a simple PTC ,

Comment: sorry by not answer the comments so fast, thanks by the support of all, ErikR, thanks by contact nippon america, it will be usefull...

Comment: Gil, thanks i will search more about circuit breakers, i answer comment as soon possible

Comment: Justme, thank you i hope you right, i expect of my dc adapters to not damaged by short circuit tests, but i prefer to ask before for not kill them, if they not have protection i think they will be hot, and may die

Comment: Autistic i'm very interested in PTC or resettable fuse, what is the more common for 5v 2a? and what is the more common for 12v 2a?, any recommendation?

Comment: If any of these dc adapters have thermal fuse embedded, i not want  kill it, thats why i looking for a way to protect these adapters, because my purpose of i buy these adapters are do test of short circuits. I comment this to all for be more explicit, about my expects

Comment: @Antelmoo If you want people to get notifications of your comments, you have to type @(name), not just (name).

Comment: @Hearth Thanks by the tip

Comment: The DK124 does have over current/short circuit protection according to the datasheet.

Comment: @Oskar Skog, DK124 protects all my adapter of short circuit by long time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any power supply rated for "input: AC 100~240V" must be a [switch-mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched-mode_power_supply) type, which always have some kind of overload protection. Supplies designed to work with chargers generally have a current limiter which holds current down to (or close to) the rating, while general purpose supplies often have 'fold-back' protection which reduces current to a low value or turns off completely when current exceeds the limit.

Linear power supplies often only have a thermal fuse embedded in the mains frequency transformer, and rely on resistance of the transformer windings and rectifier circuit to survive momentary short circuits. You don't see many of these today because they are large, heavy, inefficient and have very poor regulation with high ripple. These units are only designed to work on a narrow voltage range (eg. "100~120V"), unless they have a switch to select different primary windings for different mains voltages.

Some linear power supplies have a regulator (linear or switching) on the low voltage side to provide the more stable voltage required for sensitive equipment, and these do have current limiting. If a linear supply is regulated it will usually be stated on the label. If not you can tell by measuring the open-circuit output voltage, which will be close to its rating (whereas unregulated supplies can be up to 50% higher).

EDIT:

Thank you for uploading the image of the inside of your adapter. We see the controller IC is a [DK-124](https://grupoautcomp.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Specification-IC-DK124.pdf), which has "Over current, Over loading, Over temperature, Over voltage and **Short circuit** Protection". Section 9.8 of the datasheet says:-

> Whenever the collector current (Ip)
> abnormally exceeds the maximum current limit of 1.3A, the controller
> would **stop operation and enters into stop status**.

This suggests the power supply will shut down when overloaded.

Comment: If any of these dc adapters have thermal fuse embedded, i not want  kill it, thats why i looking for a way to protect these adapters, because my purpose of i buy these adapters are do test of short circuits.

Comment: Only linear supplies with mains frequency transformers have thermal fuses, which are designed to blow if the transformer gets too hot or is run on a much higher voltage than normal (eg. 120V transformer on 230V). Your adapters are switching types. They should limit current or shut down quicker than a correctly rated fuse would blow. Using a fuse for secondary protect while testing should be fine, because it shouldn't blow.

Comment: thanks by the information, add some images that could be useful, so that you guide me, what PPTC fuse can i use for 5v 2a? and what PPTC fuse can i use for 12v 2a, if you may know?

Comment: "This suggests the power supply will shut down when overloaded." It means my adapter will not die if i made a short circuit in the output by a long time, right?

Comment: Correct, if it does it what it says then it should not die. So the only question is - do you trust it? I wouldn't want to use a switching power supply that couldn't handle being short-circuited. But since you are testing it, why not test it to find what happens when you make a 'long time' short-circuit? If it shuts off, and then restarts when the short is removed or with a power cycle, then it's all good.

Comment: Thanks, I trust and I will try it, I also discovered something interesting, that both adapters have a hidden led, which means it is most likely prepared for a short circuit, since usually those that include a led is to warn that the connection is being interrupted , I will have to make some small holes in my adapter to be able to see the status of the led, I did not find an appropriate answer for the proposed situation, but your guide was very useful and all of the others who proposed the information of DK-124 ic. I vote you as best answer.